# Field types missing on production

Tags: heroku, keystonejs

We're having problem with some field types on our production server. Some field types are missing, causing the admin interface to crash when trying to list all items. The fields we're having problems with are so far `Date` and `CloudinaryImages` (note that `DateTime` and `CloudinaryImage` works fine).

When inspecting the source on our staging server and comparing to our production server we see the following difference in the compiled js files:

`example.com/js/fields.js` on **staging**:

```
exports.Fields = {
  text: require("types/text/TextField"),
  textarea: require("types/textarea/TextareaField"),
  html: require("types/html/HtmlField"),
  cloudinaryimage: require("types/cloudinaryimage/CloudinaryImageField"),
  select: require("types/select/SelectField"),
  relationship: require("types/relationship/RelationshipField"),
  datetime: require("types/datetime/DatetimeField"),
  boolean: require("types/boolean/BooleanField"),
  embedly: require("types/embedly/EmbedlyField"),
  cloudinaryimages: require("types/cloudinaryimages/CloudinaryImagesField"),
  numberarray: require("types/numberarray/NumberArrayField"),
  code: require("types/code/CodeField"),
  number: require("types/number/NumberField"),
  textarray: require("types/textarray/TextArrayField"),
  url: require("types/url/UrlField"),
  file: require("types/file/FileField"),
  email: require("types/email/EmailField"),
  name: require("types/name/NameField"),
  password: require("types/password/PasswordField")
};
```

`example.com/js/fields.js` on **production**:

```
exports.Fields = {
  text: require("types/text/TextField"),
  textarea: require("types/textarea/TextareaField"),
  html: require("types/html/HtmlField"),
  cloudinaryimage: require("types/cloudinaryimage/CloudinaryImageField"),
  select: require("types/select/SelectField"),
  relationship: require("types/relationship/RelationshipField"),
  datetime: require("types/datetime/DatetimeField"),
  boolean: require("types/boolean/BooleanField"),
  embedly: require("types/embedly/EmbedlyField"),
  numberarray: require("types/numberarray/NumberArrayField"),
  code: require("types/code/CodeField"),
  number: require("types/number/NumberField"),
  textarray: require("types/textarray/TextArrayField"),
  url: require("types/url/UrlField"),
  file: require("types/file/FileField"),
  email: require("types/email/EmailField"),
  name: require("types/name/NameField"),
  password: require("types/password/PasswordField")
};
```

An eagle eyed reader can see that the staging server has `cloudinaryimages: require("types/cloudinaryimages/CloudinaryImagesField"),` while the production server does not. `Date` does not appear at all in these, perhaps because we removed all fields using that type the last time we encountered this problem?

Our site is hosted on Heroku. We've tried disabling node cache and rebuilding. We've tried promoting the staging build to production. The problem still persists. Our production server has environment set to `production`.

Does the build of the `fields.js` file depend on what fields we use? And how come our production server doesn't get them?

Any help appreciated.

Keystone version: `4.0.0-beta.8` *(forked with a small addition not relevant to this)*

Comment: What specific version of Keystone are you using?

Comment: @Stennie I added that information now, my bad!

Comment: Hrm .. I don't seem to have `js/fields.js`. Is your production app running with `NODE_ENV=production`? If so, one guess is that your change to this JavaScript file may not have triggered the admin bundle (which is built with Browserify) to rebuild. You could try moving/removing `node_modules/keystone/admin/bundles/` in your production app which should trigger a rebuild on the next request if you are using the `production` env setting. If you aren't using `production` env, can you edit your question with the full path to `fields.js`?

Comment: I've added some details now. I'll see if I'm able to test renaming that folder.

Comment: Does the bundle builder only build based on what field types are being used?

Comment: The admin UI path `js/fields.js` serves a browserify bundle including all available field types irrespective of which ones are used in your Keystone app. If you have identical application code deployed in staging & production, my theory is that cached bundle files may be out of sync in your `production` env. I'm not certain that's your issue, but I've had a similar problem where `NODE_ENV=production` didn't notice a file change and required removing the bundle files to refresh. However, I've also been testing different Keystone versions so quirks of my environment may be self-inflicted :).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm circumventing the issue for the moment and will hopefully be able to come back to the issue to actually solve it.